# How to view larger objects in blender

Tags: 3d-view, units

I have imported a large topo surface inthe DXF format it's area is around 10000 sq meter .
When I have imported the DXF  file  is not visible but the properties of that DXF file is available in property panel
Plz tell how to slove this issue

And I have also tried to import the Revit Architecture file in form of DXF  but same problem has been occurred for that too

Comment: Two options: make the object smaller, or move the camera (or the view) way back to encompass the object. You will need to change the clip start and end so that  the model fits within the depth buffer.

Comment: The third option is to change the units for the scene from meters to kilometers